# I am getting error installing knife-github-cookbooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

When ever I am doing gem install knife-github-cookbooks on centos 7, I am getting below error. Please help

```
ERROR:  Error installing knife-github-cookbooks:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h
```

Comment: What's your operating system? Depending on that you have to install the ruby source packages, i.e., `ruby-all-dev` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you use ChefDK on workstations, as it includes all the needed headers and whatnot. Make sure you use `chef gem install`.